# Doubts about design Shift schema in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, api

I am coding an API Rest for a small project about Shifts for the employees but I am stuck in how to design the models. I found a way to design it but I have doubts if it is the best way.

My collections are:

- Users: (Employees)
- Positions: (Employee Position)
- Shift: ( start - end time based on the employee position.)
- Record: (day of the shift, shift and employees)
- Rota: (information about rota)

Users can have more than one position.

The shifts only have one position.

Records collect the shifting the array of employees and references about rota.

I will simplify my code:

```js
const User = Schema({
   name: {type: String},
   position: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref 'Positions'}]

});
```

```js
const positions = Schema({
   name: {type: String}
});
```

```js
const Shifts = Schema({
   start_time: {type: Date},
   end_time : {type: Date},
   position: {type: Schema.Type.ObjectID, ref 'Positions'}
});
```

```js
const Records = Schema({
   start_date: {type: Date},
   end_date : {type: Date},
   shift: {type: Schema.Type.ObjectID, ref 'Shifts'},
   employees:[{type: Schema.Type.ObjectID, ref 'Users'}]

});
```

Do you think it is a good design to develop the schema or not?

Anything to improve? or something to change?

Comment: Do you really need a "Positions" collection if there is only a name in it? Wouldn't "position: { type: String }` be enough in the user entry?

Comment: Hi, well i add a position collection because, the users can have more than one position.

Comment: Then it could be an array of strings. Having a Collection of positions would make sense though if the users can manage positions (create / delete etc.)

Comment: True,  mi idea is that the manager can add a new position if he need it. But what sould i do with shifts collections and records, because when i do a query positions apear in everywhere and i do not know if it good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience too many references in MongoDB slows the MongoDB. Your design is good when you are relational database.The concept of a Document database is that it eliminates lots of joins. Try to place as much in a single document as you can. Because MongoDB documents have structure, and because you can efficiently query within that structure Also you don't have to normalise the data like you would in SQL.

Comment: I totally agree, but the answer might be more useful if you would apply that to the actuall OPs usecase

Comment: Good point. I will try to do it like you said. I can place records and shifts together . Thank you for your help